# Leaflet: intersection click event with Point

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to catch intersecting features. So when a user clicks on the map I would like to identify all layers that has been clicked on, and show the menu - from which parcel the user wants to get info. For example, in the picture below, there should be 3 options:

1. Click outside of polygons: 0 intersection features (click doesn't intersect with any layer).
2. Click inside the polygon: 1 intersection feature (user's click intersects with 1 layer), so intersectingFeatures array has 1 object.
3. Click on the point: 2 intersecting features: Polygon and Point (user's click intersects with 2 layers), so intersectingFeatures array has 2 objects.

But somehow I can't catch intersection with Point. Function `intersects()` just doesn't recognize intersection with Point. Is there any other way to capture click intersection with Point geometry type? (catch intersection with Polygon works perfectly though).

```
   useMapEffect(({instance}) => { // instance is a Map object

    const onClick = (e: any) => {
        const clickBounds = L.latLngBounds(e.latlng, e.latlng);
        intersectingFeatures = [];

        for (const l in (instance as any)._layers) {
            const overlay = (instance as any)._layers[l];

            if (overlay.feature) {
                let bounds;
                
                if (overlay.getBounds) {
                    bounds = overlay.getBounds();
                } else if (overlay._latlng) { // for Point
                     bounds = L.latLngBounds(overlay._latlng, overlay._latlng);
                }
                
                 if (bounds && clickBounds.intersects(bounds)) {
                     intersectingFeatures.push(overlay);
                 }
            }
        }
        console.log(intersectingFeatures);
    }

    instance.on("click", onClick);

    return () => {
        instance.off("click", onClick);
    }    }, [intersectingFeatures]);
```

[image]

The same with `leaflet-pip` library. If I use it this way (instead of `intersects()` function), Point features also doesn't fall into results array, Polygons only.

```
const results = leafletPIP.pointInLayer(e.latlng, L.geoJSON(overlay.toGeoJSON()));
```

How I create Points:

```
const featureObj = rows.map((data:any) => {
                    if(featureProps.featureType === "point"){
                    const {_X_COORD:longitude,_Y_COORD:latitude}:
                        {_X_COORD:string,_Y_COORD:string} = data;
                    const wktPoint = `Point (${longitude} ${latitude})`;

                    const geometry = Leaflet.L.geoJSON(
                        {
                            ...wkt2geojson(wktPoint) as GeoJsonObject,
                            properties: {
                                data: (featureProps.featureLabel) ? (featureProps.featureLabel(data)) : "",
                                type: "Custom-Point"
                            },
                        } as any,
                        {
                            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
                                return L.circle(latlng, {
                                    radius: 10,
                                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                                })
                            }
                        });

                    return geometry;}}
```

Comment: How is circle defined? As `L.circleMarker`? If so, it has no dimension regarding vector layer, it's only a point.

Comment: @TomazicM, exactly, it is defined as `L.circleMarker`. I thought since circleMarker has radius, it is not a simple Point, and it can be used in this case. What would be the best approach then?

Comment: Here it gets a bit complicated if you want to have marker size in pixels, since at each zoom level it covers different map area. In short, for each zoom level you would have to calculate marker radius in meters, create buffer with that radius around the point and check if click coordinate falls within it. [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library can help you with that.

Comment: If you would define your circle as `L.circle`, this would make it a vector layer with dimensions, but then it's size on screen would change with zoom change.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment is wrong. `L.circle` vector layer also behaves as a point, not as a circular area. Simplest solution would then be to use `turf.circle` to create GeoJSON polygonal approximation of the circle.

Comment: Thanks, @TomazicM, not sure why, but `L.circle` actually works for intercepting features on click! and `L.circleMarker` really doesn't work.

Comment: Good! My last comment was based upon looking at the data structure of `L.circle` object and making some assumptions, but I didn't try to test `.intersects` method.

Comment: @TomazicM, By the way, it is interesting to know about performance of such a solution. Is it a good approach to find intersecting features by looping over all features in all layers, or is there any better way to do that?